# Can you build a ship in the Caspian Sea?

Tags: axis-and-allies

The Caspian Sea is a lone body of water south of Caucasus and north of the Middle East. It is also not connected to any other sea location and does not have a zone number. Here is how it appears in *Axis & Allies 1941*:

[image: The Caspian Sea, from Axis & Allies 1941]

Is it permitted to build a ship in this location in any version of *Axis & Allies*? I realize that it is rather impractical to do so, but in the rare chance that you want to invade a bordering country with some naval support on your side and have the ability to pull it off, is it permitted to build a ship in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are versions of Axis and Allies that allow building ships in the Caspian Sea. This is the exception tough. In Axis and Allies 1941/1942, the Caspian Sea is not considered a sea zone and you cannot build any ships there.

In Axis and Allies 1940 Europe/Global, [the Caspian Sea is a sea zone](http://www.harrisgamedesign.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=4278). Therefore, you can build ships there.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can build a ship in any sea zone adjacent to a "factory" owned by your country.

In the beginning of many versions of the game, Russia has two factories, one in the Moscow zone, and one in Karelia (Leningrad), but none in the Caucasus. Russia needs first to build a factory in the Caucasus (or some Middle Eastern square adjacent to the Caspian Sea), which will then allow her to build a ship in the Caspian Sea.